# full stop at the end of section and subsection numbering

Tags: fonts

I am using IEEE tran journal TeX file for writing document but I am facing problem in section numbering in my document. It appears as

> 1, 1.1

with `\documentclass[journal,compsec]{iEEEtran}`. I want the numbering as

> 1., 1.1., 1.2., 2.

and so on.

By using `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}\arabic{subsection}.}` I got

> 1., 2., 3., 3..2, 3..4, 3..5

instead of

> 1., 2., 3., 3.2., 3.4., 3.5.

I want to get a full stop at the end of section and subsection numbering.

Please guide me what to do.

Comment: Note if you are writing to a journal, DO NOT change the setup, that is not your decision

Comment: Changing `\thesection` to include the subsection number is truly a recipe for unexpected results!

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want

```
\documentclass[journal,compsoc,conference]{IEEEtran}
```

Note `compsoc`, instead of `compsec` that has no meaning.

```
\documentclass[journal,compsoc,conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\subsection{Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]